# Why do I get the information Enum argument can be null in Java, but exhaustive when contains no null branch in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, android-livedata

Code B works well, but the Code A get the following warning prompt (It can run), why?

*Enum argument can be null in Java, but exhaustive when contains no null branch*

I think `_playState.value` can be null in Code B too, do I should add null branch when I use `exhaustive when` in Code B?

**Code A**

```
private val _selectAction = MutableLiveData<ESelect>()
val selectAction: LiveData<ESelect> = _selectAction

selectAction.observe(mLifecycleOwner) {
   when(it) {               //Enum argument can be null in Java, but exhaustive when contains no null branch                                   
         ESelect.SelectAll    -> binding.chSelect.isChecked = true
         ESelect.UnselectAll  -> binding.chSelect.isChecked = false
         ESelect.NoAction     -> Unit
   }
}



enum class ESelect{
    SelectAll,
    UnselectAll,
    NoAction  
}
```

**Code B**

```
private val _playState=MutableLiveData<EPlayState>()

 override fun playOrPause(filename: String) {
        when (_playState.value) {
           EPlayState.STOPPED -> play(filename)
           EPlayState.PLAYING -> pause()
           EPlayState.PAUSED  -> resume()
        }
    }


enum class EPlayState {
    STOPPED,
    PLAYING,
    PAUSED
}
```

Comment: What is the type of `it` in  Code A?

Comment: See https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#null-safety-and-platform-types

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`LiveData` is written in `Java`. The second parameter that you pass to the `observe()` function is an anonymous implementation of Java interface `Observer`. Since Java doesn't know anything about nullability in Kotlin, the parameter `it` assumed to be nullable.

Comment: Thanks! Do you mean `selectAction.observe` is an anonymous implementation of Java interface? so the system give the warning prompt, and  `when (_playState.value) { }` is an Kotlin implementation, it's perfect without warning prompt, right?

Comment: In Code B, you have created `_playState` as LiveData for nonull object type `<ESelect>` in Kotlin, that is why it does not give you warning. In Code A value is coming from Java code which is not marked as @NonNull in Java.